# [gem]と[rubygems]のタグの統合

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

以下の`[gem]`と`[rubygems]`の両方のタグが存在するようですが、実質同じものですし統合して片方をタグシノニム化すべきではないでしょうか。

#### [gem]タグの説明

```
Gem (ジェム)は RubyGems パッケージ管理ソフトウェアにおいて、コードがまとめられたものを指します。また、 gem は、 RubyGems ツールを管理するためののコマンドラインプログラムでもあります。
```

#### [rubygems]タグの説明

```
Ruby用のパッケージ管理システムで、gemと呼ばれるパッケージのインストールや依存解決を行います。
```

Comment: +1: 本家 Stack Overflow では[シノニムになっていました](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rubygems/synonyms)。Ruby に詳しくないので伺いたいのですが、どちらがマスターの方が自然でしょうか？

Comment: RubyGemsの内部で扱うパッケージ的なものがGemなのでRubyGemsの方がマスターでいいと思います。本家でもそうなっているようですし。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

特に反対意見が無いようなので、[rubygems](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rubygems) をマスターとしてタグのマージとシノニム化を行いました :)

また、マージに伴って [rubygems](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rubygems) のタグ抜粋を以下のように書き換えました。

> RubyGemsはRuby用のパッケージ管理ツールであり、gemと呼ばれるパッケージのインストールや依存解決を行います。gemの仕組みや、gemコマンドについての質問にもこのタグを使ってください。